# Control Key & shift key closes Files Window in UBUNTU 14.04 gnome 3.12

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-keyring

When I press control key or shift key it closes opened files and files system in UBUNTU 14.04, I really can't understand what is the problem why its happening, please help I am using UBUNTU 14.04 & gnome version 3.12.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the reason of this error is your scrollbar settings.
Run Unity-Tweak-Tool and go to scrolling settings. Change Scrollbars to default Overlay.

Comment: You Are hero Man You saved My Friend Life